# Symfony matching route when absolute asset url attached

Tags: symfony

I have a weird issue happening. My app uploads an image then returns an absolute URL eg. http://localhost:8000/uploads/images/12-6.jpg to the path via json through from where the user can crop amongst other edits.

This seems to work fine in production mode but I am having problems in dev because for some reason the app decides to match the route defines below:

```
category:
    path:  /{parent}/{id}/{category}
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Default:showCat", category: '' }
```

Is there anyway I can prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks more like a problem in your Web server conf. Can you paste Apache/Nginx configuration in dev?

Comment: I'm using the built-in server that is initiated in the cli by typing php bin/console server:run. Not sure whether its configuration lies

Comment: Oh ok, never used it. No idea then :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is working in production because you didn't clear the cache with env=prod?

Your route is too broad, it match almost everything. `uploads/images/12-6.jpg` match your route with parent: `upload`, id : `images`, category `12-6.jpg`.

Take a look at [the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) if you need more information

You should add a prefix to your route (like `categ/{parent}/{id}/{category}`) or use requirements like below:

```
category:
    path:  categ/{parent}/{id}/{category}
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Default:showCat", category: '' }
    requirements:
        id:  \d+
```

I recommend you to use a prefix AND a requirement, to not have future route problems

Comment: Thanks for this, I already had issues before this but unfortunately it's a news site and they kind of follow a certain pattern with the paths. I hope the requirements will help in the meantime

Comment: I added the requirement but still symfony tries to match the route and I am getting an No route found for "GET /uploads/images/12-6.jpg error

Comment: for you information, you can also use like /{parent}/{id}/categ-{category}

Comment: It's a bit long considering I am using sonata admin. Here is the paste http://pastebin.com/07hHDkhu. Thanks again for taking your time